# inaccurately reading from file logic error Python

Tags: python, logic

Hi I have the following text file on which I am using a csv reader:

```
number,obstacle,location,message
1,gobacktostart,8,Sorry but you've landed on a dangerous number, back to the start for you!
2,movetosquare42,matrix[1][0],The meaning of life is 42 or so they say, and that's where you're headed
```

I wish to (at the end) retrieve the number 8 from the row that starts 1,gobacktostart,8....etc.

My code is:

```
def gobacktostart():

    with open("obstacles.txt","r") as f:
        idnumber="1"
        fReader=csv.reader(f)
        for row in fReader:
            for field in row:
                if field==idnumber:
                    print(row[3])

                    player1position==row[2]
                    print(player1position)
```

and the undesired output however, is:

```
>>> 
Sorry but you've landed on a dangerous number
1
>>>
```

I do need to read the value into the variable player1position in order to pass it on to another function at a different part of the program.

Any thoughts on solving this logic error? Why is it printing "1", when row[2] refers to the 8. Also, Row[3] seems to execute properly in the previous line....

Comment: You used `==` (equality testing) instead of assignment (`=`). The result of the equality test is ignored and you just get *whatever object `player1position` was already referencing*.

Comment: Note that there is no need to use `for field in row` here. Just test if `row[0] == idnumber`; you don't need to test each and every column in the row when only the first column has to match.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for equality not assignment in `player position == row[2]`